# how can i calculate growth order of this entire function?

Tags: complex-analysis

when $\alpha\gt1$, then show that $$F_\alpha(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-|t|^\alpha}e^{2\pi izt}dt$$

is of growth order $\alpha\over{\alpha-1}$

i proved that it is an entire function and growth order is less or equal to $\alpha\over{\alpha-1}$

but i cannot draw that it is order of  $\alpha\over{\alpha-1}$ since i don't know how to draw opposite direction

of the inequality

how can i derive?

Comment: Some possible solutions are now here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2027168/growth-order-of-entire-functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** If we replace $t$ with $|z|^{\frac{1}{\alpha-1}} u$ we may estimate the integral through [Laplace's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace's_method).

Comment: is it possible to show that order larger or equal then the number? by the method?

Comment: @Moon: Laplace's method provides an asymptotic expansion, not only an inequality, see the very last paragraph of the linked Wikipedia page.

Comment: when i substituted t as your hint, in the exponential term it appears $z\over|z|$ which magnitude is 1, can i ignore this term?

Comment: where is the very last paragraph of the document? i cannot derive complex version of laplace method.